# Best way to handle large file in android

Tags: android, arrays, base64

I'm trying to get the 'pdf' file from local folder and converting it to byte array as shown below. As the pdf is large it throws me an 'Out of memory exception'

So I would like to overcome this issue as my users will upload files more than 10-20 MB files.

Conversion file to byte array:

```
public static String convertFileToByteArray(File f) {
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

            Log.e("Byte array", ">" + byteArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

Exception Occurred:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
at android.util.Base64OutputStream.internalWrite(Base64OutputStream.java:141)
at android.util.Base64OutputStream.write(Base64OutputStream.java:101)
at com.sampleapp.testapp.testapp.MainActivity.convertFileToByteArray(MainActivity.java:547)
at com.sampleapp.testapp.testapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:401)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3677)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3724)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:175)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the objective of reading the file into memory? When you say "my users will upload files more than 10-20 MB files", you mean upload to a server? This is what you need?

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana- Absolutely Xavier...I'm trying to post the file to my server.

Comment: Then the solution is to have two streams at the same time, one to read to memory, another one to send to server. You read a chunk of data to an intermediate buffer (e.g. 4096 bytes) and send it, and repeat using this single, small buffer.

Comment: Also, I suggest to use some kind of library to do that, like the well-know Retrofit https://github.com/square/retrofit

Comment: Thats a good one...do you have any sample for this ?

Comment: There are plenty of those in blogs, tutorials... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=retrofit+example+upload+file

Comment: You can also use Koush's Ion : https://github.com/koush/ion

Comment: https://github.com/koush/ion#post-multipartform-data-and-read-json-with-an-upload-progress-bar    | Sample link

Comment: Posted everything together as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to have two streams at the same time, one to read to memory, another one to send to server. You read a chunk of data to an intermediate buffer (e.g. 4096 bytes) and send it, and repeat using this single, small buffer.

Also, I suggest to use some kind of library to do that, like the well-know Retrofit github.com/square/retrofit

There are [plenty of examples](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=retrofit%20example%20upload%20file) on how to use it in blogs, tutorials... [This tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) looks quite good, and targets Retrofit 2.x.

Answer (score -1):

You can used `android:largeHeap` in AndroidManifest.xml for your application to let the system know that you need more memory. Check it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).

But i suggest you to avoid loading the whole file to the memory and think about pagination or somethink like that.

Comment: `Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.`

But upvoted this, because I needed it.

Comment: Well, I mentioned, that the better way is to optimize memory usage